# Displaying JSON Data from API in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have an array of objects with properties name and then two arrays (NCMovies and KRMovies).  I want to display this data on HTML and will style it thereafter with CSS.  An example of the JSON.stringify data is below.  I have tried appendChild and appendNode and that is not working.

JavasScript:

```
document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(answer)
```

Which Shows on Screen:

```
[{"name":"Laurence Fishburne","NCMovies":["Running with the Devil"],"KRMovies":["The Matrix Revolutions","The Matrix Reloaded","The Matrix"]}
```

Comment: "Which Shows on Screen" — So you assign JSON to innerHTML and it shows JSON in the document. What's what I would expect. What did you expect?

Comment: "I have tried appendChild and appendNode and that is not working." — How did you try? Provide a [mcve]. What do you mean by "not working"? What happened? What did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery to handle it in simpler way.

```js
var arrObject = [{"name":"Laurence Fishburne","NCMovies":["Running with the Devil"],"KRMovies":["The Matrix Revolutions","The Matrix Reloaded","The Matrix"]},{"name":"Laurence Fishburne 2","NCMovies":["Running with the Devil 2"],"KRMovies":["The Matrix Revolutions 2","The Matrix Reloaded 2","The Matrix 2"]}];

var ul = $("<ul>");

$.each(arrObject,function(){
var obj = this;
ul.append($("<li>").text(obj.name));

var _ul1 = $("<ul>");
$.each(obj.NCMovies,function(){
  _ul1.append($("<li>").text(this));
});
ul.append(_ul1);

var _ul1 = $("<ul>");
$.each(obj.KRMovies,function(){
  _ul1.append($("<li>").text(this));
});
ul.append(_ul1);

});

$("#result").html(ul);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the final code in vanilla javascript:

```js
var data=[{"name":"Laurence Fishburne","NCMovies":["Running with the Devil"],"KRMovies":["The Matrix Revolutions","The Matrix Reloaded","The Matrix"]}];
function mapper(item){
  var container=document.createElement('div');
  
  var title=document.createElement('h1');
  title.innerText=item.name;
  container.appendChild(title);
  
  var ncMovies=document.createElement('h2');
  ncMovies.innerText="NCMovies";
  container.appendChild(ncMovies);
  
  var ul1=document.createElement('ul');
  item.NCMovies.forEach(function(it){
    var li= document.createElement('li');
    li.innerText=it;
    ul1.appendChild(li);
  });
  container.appendChild(ul1);
  
    
  
  var krMovies=document.createElement('h2');
  krMovies.innerText="KRMovies";
  container.appendChild(krMovies);
  
   var ul2=document.createElement('ul');
  item.KRMovies.forEach(function(it){
    var li= document.createElement('li');
    li.innerText=it;
    ul2.appendChild(li);
  });
  container.appendChild(ul2);
  
  return container;
  
}
var elements=data.map(mapper);

var body=document.querySelector('body');
elements.forEach(function(element){
  body.appendChild(element);
})
```